# Is there a way to integrate google calendar api in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-calendar-api

I want to make an android app with unity. This app Will make use of your (google) calender to determine certain things. Is there a way to read google calendar appointments and specifically appointment durations/times?

Comment: you can use google calendar api.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android#step_1_acquire_a_sha1_fingerprint

This may help you

Comment: Does this work with Unity? Or are you suggesting I develop the app in Android studio?

Comment: I don't know exactly whether there is an api for calling calendar with unity. U can also ask question in http://forum.unity3d.com/ for further details.